# Iframe is showing up blank when link should open inside box when user clicks button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to open a link in an iframe after you select a radio button, but it's showing up blank.

```
<form target="myIframe" style="display:inline;" name="cashDonation" id="cashDonation" action="https://www.paypal-donations.com/pp-charity/PayPalDonationController" method="POST" onsubmit=return submitDonation();>

<iframe name='myIframe' src="" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Here's the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/nsilverblatt/cn57sx6s/

Comment: ?? When you click the PayPal donation button, it does open.

Comment: Not when I click one of the options and then on the donate button

Comment: I just tested your jsfiddle.  It loads just fine when clicking the button with and without a radio button selected.

Comment: I'm only getting something to happen in the box when I don't click a radio button, and only the big yellow button. Tested on Chrome and Safari. Weird

Comment: Did you check the console? Lots of [errors](http://i.imgur.com/D1vfmBV.png) being thrown due to origin

Comment: @KevinJantzer any idea how to go about fixing these errors?

Comment: Have you tried your code outside of jsfiddle? Do you still get those errors?

Comment: This is what I get on Chrome http://imgur.com/e6b1fyI

Comment: @Nate – unfortunately, I dont think there is a way around it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7271913/484780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load PayPal into an iframe due to cross-origin. This is for security reasons.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271913/484780