# in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options android paypal

Tags: android, paypal, webview

I have the next issue with my integration with paypal web, what happend well i trying to use webview for show client paypal with checkout.js using  my account sandbox everything work fine, but when try to pass to production when the user try to pay and later try to sign in the iframe in paypal in web console from webview return something like this:

Refused to display 'https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=checkout&ctxId=ullndg30c5acef3b074755860900b24700c07f&returnUri=%2Fwebapps%2Fhermes&state=%3Fflow%3D1-' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X-Frame-Options forbidding redirect to PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271737/x-frame-options-forbidding-redirect-to-paypal)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the istructions in "Best-for-now Legacy Browser Frame Breaking Script" from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

In this manner I solved the same issue.

Best regards